# JSON Schema validation: validate array of objects

Tags: php, json, validation, schema, jsonschema

I get following JSON and would like to validate it.

```
[
    {
        "remindAt": "2015-08-23T18:53:00+02:00",
        "comment": "Postman Comment"
    },
    {
        "remindAt": "2015-08-24T18:53:00+02:00",
        "comment": "Postman Comment"
    }
]
```

My schema looks currently as following

```
{
    "type": "array",
    "required": true,
    "properties": {
        "type": "object",
        "required": false,
        "additionalProperties": false,
        "properties": {
            "remindAt": {
                "required": true,
                "type": "string",
                "format": "date-time"
            },
            "comment": {
                "required": true,
                "type": "string"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is not working. It validates to true even if I remove comment from JSON ddata. I guess structure of my schema file is wrong.

For validating I use following library 
https://packagist.org/packages/justinrainbow/json-schema

Can please someone explain to me what I do wrong and how I properly validate given JSON data?

Thanks in advance

Comment: with which code do you validate this ?

Comment: I use justin rainbows library to validate the schema against the json data

https://packagist.org/packages/justinrainbow/json-schema

Comment: when you look json-schema website, the "required" is not at the same place as in your exemple : http://json-schema.org/examples.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are some errors in your schema. First, you are using *properties* for an array object. *properties* is a clause for objects, not arrays, so it will be ignored.

From [json-schema v4](http://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-validation.html), *required* is an array.

The following schema will require remindAt and comment properties for all items in the array:

```
{
    "type": "array",
    "items": {
        "additionalProperties": false,
        "properties": {
            "remindAt": {
                "type": "string",
                "format": "date-time"
            },
            "comment": {
                "type": "string"
            }
        },
        "required": ["remindAt", "comment"]
    }
}
```

Comment: You might need to use _False_ instead of _false_